# Random "lost connection to device" after inserting AssetImage

Tags: android, image, flutter, dart

Ever since I added an AssetImage to one of my screens in my Flutter project, the app will crash after about 5-10 seconds. Once I do `flutter run`, I get this output:

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Flutter is taking longer than expected to report its views. Still trying...
W/le.climb_grade(31412): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->getSourceNodeId()J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/le.climb_grade(31412): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord;->getSourceNodeId()J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/le.climb_grade(31412): Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->mChildNodeIds:Landroid/util/LongArray; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/le.climb_grade(31412): Accessing hidden method Landroid/util/LongArray;->get(I)J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/Gralloc3(31412): mapper 3.x is not supported
W/RenderThread(31412): type=1400 audit(0.0:99213): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=24913 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c179,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc    (31412): Access denied finding property "vendor.gralloc.disable_ahardware_buffer"
```

This is the file where the asset image is. It is the default screen for when the app opens.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Start extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartState createState() => _StartState();
}

class _StartState extends State<Start> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('lib/img/start_bg.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                BlendMode.dstATop
            ),
          )
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'CLIMB GRADER',
                style: GoogleFonts.titilliumWeb(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontSize: 38.0
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not place asset image into `lib` folder 
You can change from

```
AssetImage('lib/img/start_bg.jpg'),
```

to `assets/img` folder

```
AssetImage('assets/img/start_bg.jpg'),
```

And update `pubsepc.yaml` like this

```
assets:
  - assets/img/
```